# Javascript function with large number of arguments

Tags: javascript

I need to call a javascript function with many arguments. Is there any way to do the same as the below code but without writing each of av1, av2,...av58?

A for loop varying from 1 to 58 may do the job. But how is the syntax while defining the function?

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function gft1(ff1, ff2, av1,av2, av3, av4, av5, av6, av7, av8,  av9,  av10,  av11,  av12,  av13,  av14,  av15,  av16,  av17,    av18,  av19,  av20,  av21,  av22,  av23,  av24,  av25,  av26,  av27,  av28,   av29,  av30,  av31,  av32,  av33,  av34,  av35,  av36,  av37,  av38,  av39,   av40,  av41,  av42,  av43,  av44,  av45,  av46,  av47,  av48,  av49,  av50,   av51,  av52,  av53,  av54,  av55,  av56,  av57,  av58)
{   
var uu=0;

    for ( y=1; y<=58;++ y)
        {
         uu = uu-(-document.getElementById('av'+y).value);
        }

document.getElementById(ff1).value=uu;
document.getElementById(ff2).value=uu;

}
var args = ['ff1','ff2'];
for (var i = 1; i <= 58; i++)
args.push("av" + i);
</script>  

</head>
 ....................................
   <html><input type="text" size="1" autocomplete="off"  onfocus="this.select()" name="<?php echo "av[$no]"?>" id="<?php echo "av{$no}" ? >" onkeyup="gft1.apply(null, args);"></html>
```

Comment: Fix or wrap `gft1()` to not require such repetitive arguments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use for loop to filling the arguments pool

then use `apply` to call it and passing the arguments

```
function gft1(){
    console.log(arguments);
}

var args = ['ff1','ff2'];
for (var i = 1; i <= 58; i++)
    args.push("av" + i);

gft1.apply(null, args);
```

see usage of `apply` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Comment: Code without explanation is not that helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you at all require to pass `av1,av2,av3....` when it can be simple done by passing `av`. Also you are not doing anything `av1,av2,av3,...` , you are just dealing with `av` & looping from 1 to 58 and appending y value to `av` to get the content from DOM.

So a function like this wont be sufficient?

```
function gft1('ff1',ff2,'av'){
var uu=0;
   for ( y=1; y<=58;++ y){
         uu = uu-(-document.getElementById('av'+y).value);
                                            // ^^ y's value will vary which will query for `av1,av2,av3..`
        }

document.getElementById(ff1).value=uu;
document.getElementById(ff2).value=uu;

}
```